# Scala function arguments with default value followed by multiarguments

Tags: function, scala, arguments

The following does not compile,

```
def echo(sep: String =" ", s: String*) = s.mkString(sep)
```

The desired function signature *would* have a first argument with default value and the rest, any number of strings.

Comment: So how would you distinguish between a defaulted first arg followed by multiple args, and a specified first arg followed by multiple args ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is problematic.

Consider this:

`echo("a", "b", "c")` : is `"a"` now the seperator or does it belong to `s`? This cannot be decided by the compiler, since both would work.

A workaround can be to use multiple parameter lists.

```
def echo(sep: String =" ")(s: String*) = s.mkString(sep)
```

Now you can use:

```
echo()("a", "b", "c") //"a b c"
echo("a")("b", "c")   //"bac"
```